# Maven downloads jars but then reports "Could not resolve dependencies"

Tags: maven, build-dependencies

I updated version dependencies in `pom.xml` to :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>imageio</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>imageio-jpeg</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When running

```
     mvn package
```

We see the new versions being downloaded:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.2.1/imageio-jpeg-3.2.1.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.2.1/imageio-jpeg-3.2.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.2.1/imageio-jpeg-3.2.1.pom (2 KB at 8.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.2.1/imageio-core-3.2.1.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.2.1/imageio-core-3.2.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.2.1/imageio-core-3.2.1.pom (1004 B at 22.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-metadata/3.2.1/imageio-metadata-3.2.1.pom
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-metadata/3.2.1/imageio-metadata-3.2.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-metadata/3.2.1/imageio-metadata-3.2.1.pom (974 B at 20.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.2.1/imageio-jpeg-3.2.1.jar
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.2.1/imageio-core-3.2.1.jar
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-metadata/3.2.1/imageio-metadata-3.2.1.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.2.1/imageio-jpeg-3.2.1.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.2.1/imageio-core-3.2.1.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-metadata/3.2.1/imageio-metadata-3.2.1.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-jpeg/3.2.1/imageio-jpeg-3.2.1.jar (58 KB at 145.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-core/3.2.1/imageio-core-3.2.1.jar (64 KB at 152.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/imageio-metadata/3.2.1/imageio-metadata-3.2.1.jar (72 KB at 171.7 KB/sec)
```

However the `package` target is still failing .. *when not being able to resolve one of those same dependencies (`imageio.jar:3.2.1`) ?*

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 2.911 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2016-06-21T13:21:39-07:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/221M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sparknet: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project org.amplab:sparknet:jar:1.0: Failure to find
>   com.twelvemonkeys.imageio:imageio:jar:3.2.1 in
>   https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of Maven snapshots repository has elapsed or
>   updates are forced -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the issue were that between `3.1.2` and `3.2.1` versions of `imagio` they have restructured their modules. Now they have `imageio-core` instead of `imageio`.

So.. updating the pom.xml as follows:

> `<dependency>
>       <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
>       <artifactId>imageio-core</artifactId>
>       <version>3.2.1</version> </dependency>`

(using `imageio-core` instead of `imageio`) seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with -U to force maven to ignore the cached artifacts in your local repository and update them. `mvn package -U`